# Remove duplicate CSS declarations across multiple files

Tags: css, duplicates, compare, diff

I'm looking to remove duplicate CSS declarations from a number of files to make implementing changes easier. Is there a tool that can help me do that?

Right now I'm faced with something like this:

```
styles.css
#content {
width:800px;
height:1000px;
background: green;
}

styles.game.css
#content {
width:800px;
height:1000px;
background: blue;
}
```

And I want this:

```
styles.css
#content {
width:800px;
height:1000px;
background: green;
}

styles.game.css
#content {
background: blue;
}
```

The total number of lines across all files is well over 10k, so techniques that rely on manual editing aren't an option.

Answer (score 13):

I wrote a tool specifically for this purpose called [csscss](http://zmoazeni.github.io/csscss/). As a bonus it also integrates with Sass and LESS. Give it a shot and let me know if you have an issues in github.

Comment: Looks really neat, but it doesn't seem to support automatic removal of duplicates and multiple files.

Comment: No, that is on purpose. There are many ways for a developer to refactor their css. And I believe automatic removal makes it harder to debug problems in the styles, after the fact.

Comment: That's what options are for.

Comment: I love that there are versions for both gulp and grunt!  https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-csscss

Answer (score 9):

helped me to clean up selectors -
CSS usage - Firebug extension to view which CSS rules are actually used.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/

[http://web.archive.org/web/20120127123107](http://web.archive.org/web/20120127123107/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/)

Answer (score 7):

I made a nodejs tool to help with this, it currently handles single files but lemme know if it helps or of any improvements, feel free to fork it and take it to another level too :)

https://npmjs.org/package/css-purge

https://github.com/rbtech/css-purge

Comment: Our latest version does this and more! http://rbtech.github.io/css-purge

Comment: Seems like it doesn't remove duplicates?

Comment: @KalpeshSingh please provide your sample CSS and how you used it: https://github.com/rbtech/css-purge/issues

Answer (score 3):

This system claim to do that:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cssmerge/?source=dlp

But I couldn't make it work, though.

So here it goes some tools to compare the CSS files. It is not as fast as an automatic solution, but would make it faster than going by visual comparison alone.

http://www.diffchecker.com/

http://www.araxis.com/merge_mac/index.html

(csscompare.codeplex.com) -> https://github.com/bertjohnson/CSSCompare

Comment: Facing a similar issue as @kotekzot, I used CSScompare. Worked like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use W3C CSS validator to remove the duplicates of the properties. Upload the css file by clicking By file upload and click on check, then go to warnings part where you can see the duplicate properties repeated. Then you can remove your duplications by going to specific line in the file.

URL: [jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_upload)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get a few warnings about background and text colors being the same, but no warning about duplicate declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the closest thing to what you're looking for is a css preprocessor and css imports. I like LESS: http://lesscss.org/

I would do something like

```
styles.css
@site-width: 800px;
@site-height: 1000px;

#content {
width: @site-width;
height: @site-height;
background: green;
}


styles.game.css
@import url("style.css");

#content {
width: @site-width;
height: @site-height;
background: blue;
}
```

EDIT: I sort of overlooked that you don't even need LESS at all, or the height and width in styles.game.css

It would just look like

```
styles.game.css
@import url("style.css");

#content {
background: blue;
}
```

Comment: An interesting solution, but in the end I would still have to deal with duplicate declarations when editing CSS, and the total number of lines in those files is well over 10k, editing them by hand is not feasible.

Comment: RE: edit, is there a way to arrive at that state without editing all the files by hand?

Comment: Not that I know of... from what you've said, it sounds like a lot of Find & Replace